# Cabal configure file options

Tags: haskell, makefile, ghc, cabal

I am using `cabal` to manage a mid-sized project (not intended for distribution). I use a `Makefile` to perform basic setup and then it calls `cabal` `configure`/`build` to build the rest of the project. I'd also like to be able to optionally profile the project using the tools built into GHC.

This seems to involve a different set of options in the `.cabal` file as well as passing the `--enable-executable-profiling` option to the `cabal` configure phase. The latter is easily doable in the `Makefile` but I can't find a clean way to tell `cabal` to use a certain set of compiler options dependent on how I call `make`. Simply put, I am looking for something akin to make rules for `.cabal` files.

Apologies if I've missed something terribly obvious here  - I am still a bit new to `Haskell`/`cabal`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two obvious options come to mind:

- Use `make`'s conditional assignment. For example, one might write

  ```
  PROF_FLAGS?=-prof -auto-all
  ```

  and then add `--ghc-options="${PROF_FLAGS}"` to the appropriate `cabal` calls throughout the `Makefile`. You can then call `make` as:

  ```
  make # use the defaults
  PROF_FLAGS="-prof -auto-all" make # another way to use the defaults
  PROF_FLAGS="" make # don't do profiling
  ```
- Use `cabal` flags. This would look something like this in your `.cabal` file:

  ```
  flag profiling
      default: True
      description: ask GHC to produce a profiling version

  executable foo
      if flag(profiling)
          ghc-options: -prof -auto-all
  ```

  Then in your `Makefile` you would either pass `-f profiling` or `-f -profiling` to `cabal` to turn this flag on and off, respectively.